# Installing rJava on different os

Tags: java, r, maven, installation, rjava

I want to use JRI in a maven project. Now, I am kind of new with bundling libraries, I never used an external library before myself, so my question might be kind of basic.

My programm should later work on any computer (independent of the OS), provided R is installed at all. 
I suppose that means I have to find the path to R anew whenever I open the program on a new computer.
However, is not the setting of this path something that is done when first installing JRI (or rJava), hence something which can not possibly be done once the jar is finished?
Do I have to install JRI on every new Computer or can I somehow bundle that and only have to install R?

Am I seeing this wrong or how do I avoid this dilemma?